# Can we have third axis in complex numbers?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers

I was just wondering can we have a third type of complex number!
Like we have three dimensions(perceivable) ,three types of quantities(vector,scalar,tensor) and moreover three types of geometries(Euclidian, Hyperbolic,Spherical)
So shouldn't the third axis of complex numbers.

I named this number 'Sery' what's your opinion in its existence?
Seary can be a negative factorial

Comment: [quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) extend complex numbers and have four components

Comment: There certainly are ways that you can extend the complex numbers.  The question however is how useful they would be.  As you continue to extend to higher and higher sets, you run the risk of losing some of the nice properties you previously had.  For instance, in the integers we had unique factorization and prime numbers.  In the rational numbers however we no longer have that.  Going from the complex numbers to the quaternions, we lose the commutativity of multiplication (*as $i\cdot j \neq j\cdot i$*).

Comment: As for "*We have three perceivable dimensions, three types of quantities, three types of geometries...*"  that is no reason in and of itself to assume there is a third type of anything else.  That is no better than [numerology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerology) which is hokum and not grounded in any actual logic or science.

Comment: oh they are like cross multiplication of vectors.

Comment: Cross product does come into play in the definitions of arithmetic for quaternions, however I am not sure that you fully understand or appreciate the connection.

Comment: i can connect it with help of physics

Comment: Can you have a third axis in the complex numbers? No. The complex numbers are well-defined, and provably do not have a third axis. Can we have have a structure with addition and multiplication on $\Bbb{R}^3$? Oh yes, there are infinitely many of them! Are any of them as nice or useful as the complex numbers? Not even close.

Comment: "*We have three perceivable dimensions,*" - I'll grant that. "*three types of quantities*," - No, that would be one type (tensors) and two of many subtypes (scalars, vectors). "*three types of geometries*" only if you restrict yourself to constant curvature, and also choose to examine only local properties, ignoring global distinctions such as compactness or orientability.